# Long authentication session and security

Tags: security, authentication

I noticed that after I authenticate in many web sites, for example in Facebook or Twitter, I am logged for a long time, more than 2-3 months, maybe a year.

So, my question is, is this secure? Or maybe they somehow change session id with time?

Answer (score 0):

Some websites use session cookies that contain your session data, which is heavily encrypted by the secret key which is only visible to the back-end. Some other websites use tokens, so basically you can get to your content by using an access token, which is only valid for short term. Then you got your refresh token which is valid for long term to refresh your short term access token, these tokens are not and should not be stored as a cookie but rather as an localstorage item because cookies are easily obtainable by cross-site javascript and localstorage is only available for the current site.